# Did Old English (Anglo-Saxon) use contractions?

Tags: contractions, old-english

German uses contractions a lot, including *im* (in+dem) and *zum* (zu+dem) to name a few. As an Old English learner, I wanted to know if there were any attested similarities. My research hereto has yielded no results.

Answer (score 30):

Yes, Old English had contractions:

> Old English contractions include *nis* from *ne is* (“is not”), *naes* from *ne waes* (“was not”), *nolde* from *ne wolde* (“would not”), *naefde* from *ne haefde* (“did not have”), and *nat* from *ne wat* (“does not know”).
>   <sub>[Is “who’s” short for “who is” or “who has”?](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2012/03/who-is.html)</sub>

For example, take a look at Ælfric's translation of Genesis 2:5:

> Mann **næs**, ðe ða eorðan worhte.

(For comparison, [here](http://biblehub.com/genesis/2-5.htm) are some modern translations of that verse.)

---

A source that covers this more in depth is [Negative Contraction: An Old and Middle English Dialect Criterion](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/27707125.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A373e3410d592e7e9cdfd357fd92256f9).

Comment: Also *ne* (not) + *æfre* (ever) = *næfre* (never), *na* (no) + *wiht* (thing, being, creature) = *nawiht* (naught) → *naht* / *noht* (not), and *na* (no) + *hwæðer* (whether) = *nahwæþer* → *nawþer* (neither). It was apparently pretty common for *ne* and *na* to be contracted to *n-*, but I don’t know offhand about other contractions.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, in  Old English, we find contractions.

> ***Nis*** is the contraction of ne is (meaning “is not”) and ***naefde*** from ne haefde (meaning “did not have”). ***Naes*** was from ne waes (meaning “was not”) and ***nolde*** came from the contraction of both ne and wolde (meaning “would not”).
>
> ***Old English was full of contractions, and these contractions have remained in place (of course, not with the same words) in our Modern English today***.

("[The History of Contractions](http://historicallyirrelevant.com/post/3505130893/the-history-of-contractions)", from *Historically Irrelevant,* by Conor Reid)

From "Orthography and Punctuation", by Vivian Salmon, in *[The Cambridge History of the English Language](https://books.google.com/books?id=CCvMbntWth8C&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=Contractions%20of%20various%20kinds%20had%20occurred%20even%20in%20Old%20and%20Middle%20English,%20as%20in%20bufan%20for%20be%20%2B%20ufan%20and%20f)%20ofjer%20for%20f)e%20ofier%20(Dobson%201968:%20836),%20and%20Hart%20comments%20on%20certain%20forms%20of%20contraction%20(though%20not%20those%20still%20valid)%20in%20his%20discussion%20of%20the%20correct%20writing%20of%20%E2%80%9Ccertaine%20propositions,%20articles%20and%20pronowns%E2%80%9D.&source=bl&ots=U2v5VRqGI7&sig=o0U97pJe_OZ6i6c66a_gRUgu8lg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKp7fT1ZrZAhVLXKwKHQIyBNEQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=Contractions%20of%20various%20kinds%20had%20occurred%20even%20in%20Old%20and%20Middle%20English%2C%20as%20in%20bufan%20for%20be%20%2B%20ufan%20and%20f)%20ofjer%20for%20f)e%20ofier%20(Dobson%201968%3A%20836)%2C%20and%20Hart%20comments%20on%20certain%20forms%20of%20contraction%20(though%20not%20those%20still%20valid)%20in%20his%20discussion%20of%20the%20correct%20writing%20of%20%E2%80%9Ccertaine%20propositions%2C%20articles%20and%20pronowns%E2%80%9D.&f=false), Volume 3: 1476-1776,* edited by Roger Lass:

> Contractions of various kinds had occurred even in Old and Middle English, as in *bufan* for *be + ufan* and *þoþer* for *þe oþer* (Dobson 1968: 836), and Hart comments on certain forms of contraction (though not those still valid) in his discussion of the correct writing of “certaine propositions, articles and pronowns”.

(p. 18)

Comment: What's with the second link?

Comment: Hyperlinks to Google Books do not work the same everywhere, note.

Comment: @JdeBP: Andriy M's comment is not related to how Google Books hyperlinks work. The link for the second source was accidentally broken in an earlier draft of the question (it was http://the%20cambridge%20history%20of%20the%20english%20language%20a%20cura%20di%20roger%20lass).

Answer (score 8):

nyllan = ne willan and similar negations (nabban = ne habban) (see bosworth-toller http://bosworth.ff.cuni.cz/023953 for nyllan)

This is covered in Mitchell and Robinson's "Guide to Old English", but I don't have my copy at hand to give page/secsion numbers).

Comment: Section 184.4c.